# Docker replicas vs gunicorn workers in production

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn, production

Do we need gunicorn or uwsgi workers when we have docker replicas? What is the best solution, make guincorn worker and replicate it on docker, or make multiple gunicorn workers?

Answer (score 0):

Based on kubernetes philosophy of [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), I believe you can mix up both approaches.